# How to allow Azure IoT edge modules to execute http requests?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

running `curl -m 20 https://www.google.com` works, however when run from within edge module container it times out:

`docker exec myModule sh -c 'curl -m 20 https://www.google.com'`

`curl: (28) Operation timed out after 20000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received`

We have the same edge environment running on several VMs, where it works as expected. It return a result.  I assume a firewall rule or other setting is blocking the request? So I compared the results of `sudo iptables -L -v` between the two VMs and these are similar.

Any suggestions on what can cause this behavior? Or what am I missing?

Comment: It's usually DNS, see: https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns

Comment: I applied the steps as described in the link, but running `iotedge check --verbose` shows that DNS is not configured, `Could not open container engine config file /etc/docker/daemon.json` Any suggestion what is going wrong?

Comment: Check if there are any bridge devices set up by docker. There's a quirk with iot edge and docker, that the bridge is not created on first startup.

ip route show and see if there's any devices starting with "br" and if the routes are correct. That was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue. The device on which the request timed out had two networks: an Ethernet and a GSM modem. Docker was bridged to the Ethernet network, which was not having an internet connection. It had to be the GSM modem. We solved this by running the [azure-iot-edge network as "host" network](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/517). So it uses the same configuration as the host machine.

```
"createOptions": {
  "NetworkingConfig": {
    "EndpointsConfig": {
      "host": {}
    }
  },
  "HostConfig": {
    "NetworkMode": "host"
  }
}
```

Running as host network solved the issue on most machines. On some other machines we got another exception, namely:

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service                                                                        not known
```

This had to do with a mismatch between `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`, see this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1982) to fix it.